# Create new page when creating post

Tags: php, html, css, sql, blogs

Currently I'm making a blog out of scratch.

I already have a login page and a "create post page". But when I create a post I just store the information inside the database.

How can I make it that I create a new page for the blog post?

Something like: [sitename].com/post.php?id=1

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Get the info from the database back on the desired page? "I want cookies" > goes to DB, and you can then get it out of the table and show "i want cookies on the webpage". I don't really understand the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Here I have an example on how you could do that (PDO). `$_GET["id"]` will take the ID from the URL. As example domain.com/post.php?id=[getid]

```
    <?php
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row["title"].' '.$row["content"];
        }
    ?>
```

And if you want to link them back to the homepage when the ID is not given, you could use this;

```
if (empty($_GET["id"])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
}
```

For linking from the index to the posts you can use;

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             echo '<a href="posts.php?id='.$row["id"].'">';
        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your `post.php` file, you can load the content from a specific post using the id provided in your url.

```
<?php

$postid = $_REQUEST['id'];
$post = someSqlFunction($postid); // <-- Replace with database code

echo '<h1>' . $post['title'] . '</h1>';
```

So if you wanted to load the post with id `15`, you simply go to `[sitename].com/post.php?id=15`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page for each and every blog post you create. When you create a blog post there must a submit or post, after submitting it goes to a php file where you write the code to store the contents of the blog post. In that very file you write some code to create html file (file programing) for blog post having particular id. And you add all the code of css,html,also contents and write to that file and save it as .html format(eg. BlogPost_1.html etc). You can store file names in database for later use.
I hope thats what you needn

Comment: I know! But I want that it automatically makes a new page when I click the submit button.